# How can i get a description of changelist from perforce?

Tags: perforce

I'm testing perforce command from cmd.

I want to get only description of changelist. So I'm looking for the solution from perforce document (https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/Home-cmdref.html)

But I have not found it yet.

Please, help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the description of a changelist, use the `p4 describe` command.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 describe 290
Change 290 by Tod@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 on 2022/03/29 17:02:28

        Tod's awesome change

Affected files ...

... //stream/child_stream/TestFile.cpp#2 edit

Differences ...

==== //stream/child_stream/TestFile.cpp#2 (text) ====

1a2
> "tod"
```

See `p4 help describe` for information on the various flags.  To omit the diffs and see just the description and list of affected files, add the `-s` flag:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 describe -s 290
Change 290 by Tod@Samwise-dvcs-1509687817 on 2022/03/29 17:02:28

        Tod's awesome change

Affected files ...

... //stream/child_stream/TestFile.cpp#2 edit
```

If for scripting purposes you need the description and *only* the description, use the `undoc` (see `p4 help undoc` for info on undoc flags) `-F` and `-Ztag` global options, like this:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -Ztag -F %desc% describe -s 290
Tod's awesome change
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.


When I looked it up, it seems that if I add the -ztag flag, each output is tagged.


And then, If I add the -F "filestring", I can get the output what I want.

And enter the desired tag in the "filestring" position and wrap the format in % at that time.

I have a question about -F flag.

I read the -F flag explanation and tested it, but I don't know what the effect is when used alone

Comment: `-F` specifies a *formatting string*, not a filespec!  There's terse documentation in `p4 help undoc`, but this blog post offers a more in depth explanation with examples: https://web.archive.org/web/20131101013248/http://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting

Comment: So, if you read through that blog entry, you can then see how I put together that `-Ztag -F %desc%` magic.  If you run `p4 -e describe` you'll see that the normal `p4 describe` output doesn't put the description into a dictionary and a message string; it just outputs the entire spec as a blob of `text`.  However, if you run `p4 -Ztag describe`, all the spec fields get tagged in a dictionary, with the description in the `desc` field!  Adding `-F %desc%` tells the client to run that dictionary through the formatting string `%desc%` which means that we only see the description.

Comment: Thank you Samwise. I get it. It really helped me a lot.